# Unable to setState on props in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been unable to setState on props I keep getting

> TypeError: props.setState is not a function

I'm trying to implement a search function

```
const HeroComp = (props) => {
        let  handleSearchSubmit = (e) => {
          props.setState({searchValue: e.target.value});
      }
      return     <div className='heroComp' >
                <form action="" >
   
                <input type="text" placeholder='search cartigory'  onChange={handleSearchSubmit}   />
                 </form>
            </div>
}

export default HeroComp;
```

When I console.log(props) I get

```
{searchValue: ""}
searchValue: ""
__proto__: Object
```

This is the parent component

```
import images from '../data/images'; //the file from which i'm importing images data

class HomePage extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            images,
            searchValue: ''
        
    }
}

    render(){
        const {images , searchValue} = this.state;
        const filteredImage = images.filter(image => image.cartigory.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue));
            return(
                <div >
                    <HeroComp searchValue={ searchValue }  />
                    <GalleryComp filteredImage={filteredImage} />
                </div>
            )
        }

}

export default HomePage;
```

I know this should be easy but I just can't see the solution .

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). That could would work if `props` were an object with a function property called `setState`. It would appear not to be such an object.

Comment: You need to pass down a method called setState from the parent to the child component or use the State hook

Comment: Add your parent component.

Comment: How did you use ```HeroComp``` Component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // set the current state
    setSearchValue(props.searchValue)
  }, [props]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional component dont have state, but you can use reactHooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const HeroComp = (props) => {
      let [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState();

      let  handleSearchSubmit = (e) => {
          setSearchValue(e.target.value);
      }
      return     <div className='heroComp' >
                <form action="" >

                <input type="text" placeholder='search cartigory'  onChange={handleSearchSubmit}   />
                 </form>
            </div>
}


export default HeroComp;
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work but there are no errors in the console